# Mongoid::Errors::AmbiguousRelationship:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, entity-relationship

### talk_groups table

```
field :parent_topic_id, type: Integer, default: -1
has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
belongs_to :parent_topic, :class_name => 'Topic', :foreign_key => :parent_topic_id
```

### topics table

```
belongs_to :talk_group
```

The relation above works well on sqlite/mysql, but doesn't work on mongoid
because when a model can't have many and belongs_to with another same model

parent_topic.talk_group will appear Mongoid::Errors::AmbiguousRelationship:    error

Answer (score 0):

the problem is caused not because "when a model can't have many and belongs_to with another same model".

it's because when mongoid looks at the `topic` model, it can't know if the `talk_group` field is referring to the `topics` or `parent_topic` relation in the `talk_group` model.

mongoid provided an option to avoid this "AmbiguousRelationship" it's the `inverse_of` option...

so to solve this issue you should alter the `topic` model to become

```
belongs_to :talk_group, inverse_of: :parent_topic
```

and the talk_group model should become

```
has_many :topics, dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :parent_topic, class_name: 'Topic'
# you can add inverse_of option on this side as well although it's not mandatory
belongs_to :parent_topic, class_name: 'Topic', inverse_of: :talk_group
```

also refere to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585079/ambiguous-relationship-in-mongoid) for more info.